# Reduce does not reflect filtering of a dimension

Tags: javascript, data-structures, mapreduce, crossfilter

When applying a filter to a group, the changes from the filtration are not reflected in my mapreduced group. I want the changes to filter down -- or to

My data is setup normally:

```
var rides = crossfilter(data),
all = rides.groupAll(),
gender = rides.dimension(function(d) { return d.gender; }),
gendersAvg = gender.group().reduce(reduceAddGender, reduceRemoveGender, reduceInitialGender).all(),
```

My map reduce functions are set up as follows:

```
function reduceAddGender(p, v) {
                p.count++;
                return p;
            }
    function reduceRemoveGender(p, v) {
                p.count--;
                return p;
    }
    function reduceInitialGender() {
                return {
                    count: 0
                };
     }
```

I perform my filtering like this:

```
gender.filter(function(d){ return d === parseInt(z[1]) || d === parseInt(z[0]) });
```

All my dimensions reflect the filter, except one. When I seek out the values of `GendersAvg` post-filtration, those values don't reflect the filters.

Ideas? Calling the average a second time doesn't change its values either.

Comment: Crossfilter group values are calculated based on filters on dimensions *other* than the dimension the group is defined on. Filters on the group's own dimension are ignored. See https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You can create a second dimension and do your filter on that one, then your original dimension will get filtered, but if the dimensions are identical there isn't usually any reason to do that because all you're doing is selecting one or more of the groups. In that case, you might as well just find the group you want directly with gendersAvg.all().filter(function(d) { return d.key === parseInt(z[1]) || d.key === parseInt(z[0])});

Comment: Thanks. The .all() is not necessary but that is one way to fix it. Will experiment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to create a separate dimension, performing my filtering such that all groups reflect its values.

```
  duration = rides.dimension(function(d) { return d.timeonbike; }),
  durations = duration.group(),

  duration2 = rides.dimension(function(d) { return d.timeonbike; }),
  durationsAvg = duration2.groupAll().reduce(reduceAddDuration, reduceRemoveDuration, reduceInitialDuration).value(),
```